# Mapping JSON to data models, need to get nested email value from a dynamic key

Tags: ios, json, swift, model, swift4

I'm using **ObjectMapper** to map data to my models and I need to fill an email property in my model. The tricky part is that depending on how the user registered (either with **email**, or with the **Facebook/Google** account) the key that holds the nested email property will reflect their registration choice. I'll give an example of my JSON data below.

In the case of regular email registration:

```
"local": {
            "email": "testclient1@mail.com",
            "password": "$2a$10$ZqqsS5F1QXmoEXnwL3v2sAxES",
            "passwordConf": "$2a$10$ZqqzsLfQXmoEXnwL3v2sAxES"
        }
```

In the case of regular Facebook or google registration:

```
"facebook": {
            "id": "10287",
            "email": "jcstclair@icloud.com"
        }

"google": {
            "id": "11514716",
            "email": "parkhomeyp@gmail.com"
        }
```

You get the idea. As you can see the key has to be different to match one of the 3 choices (local, facebook or google) in order to reach in an get email. One solution to this problem is to use enums. I'll post a relevant portion of my model.

```
import ObjectMapper

struct Client: Mappable {

    enum EmailType: String {
        case local = "local"
        case facebook = "facebook"
        case google = "google"
    }

    var emailType: String?

    init?(map: Map) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        emailType       <- map["\(EmailType.RawValue()).email"]
    }
```

The idea is to use string interpolation so it will find a match with the enum above. The **.email** allows me to get the nested property. This seems like a logical solution but it returns **nil** for the emailType property, so clearly it is not mapping it correctly.

Now that you've seen my JSON and my data model, what do you think is the best way to get to the email property, no matter which type of key it has. I want to avoid creating 3 properties for local, fb and google if possible, I want it to be succinct but dynamic. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve I suggest to create separate model classes since it is easy to modified for future updates

What you have done is not correct. You have just created   `EmailType` 's `RawValue` Object and  it will always return empty

```
    emailType       <- map["\(EmailType.RawValue()).email"]
```

if you print

```
 print("\(EmailType.RawValue()).email")
```

Output you get is

> .email

I don't have much better idea with `Map` still What you you need is to tell try each case of enum for getting data

My suggestion is you need to check `nil` in `emailType` String

Try This code

```
    emailType       <- (map["\(EmailType.local).email"] ?? map["\(EmailType. facebook).email"] ||  map["\(EmailType. google).email"] )
```

Hope it is helpful to you

**EDIT\UPDATE**

I did research on `Mappble` and found that following is helpful to you

You are getting error because `Map` is not returning non-optional value. So to get rid of it you need to use `map.JSON`

```
   if map.JSON[EmailType.local.rawValue] != nil {
        emailType       <-  (map["\(EmailType.local).email"] )
    } else if map.JSON[EmailType.facebook.rawValue] != nil {
        emailType       <-  (map["\(EmailType.facebook).email"] )
    } else if map.JSON[EmailType. google.rawValue] != nil {
        emailType       <-  (map["\(EmailType.google).email"] )
    }
```

Pl Let me know if you still facing issue.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this code but it didn't work, I ended up with this error, "Cannot convert value of type 'Map' to expected argument type 'Bool", any ideas on how to fix this? Btw, what did you mean by creating a separate model class? A separate model for the email??

Comment: Wow this worked perfectly, I noticed you made a small typo because you put EmailType.facebook twice but after I fixed that it worked like a charm! Thank you so much!